# Protect password field in a database

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

I have a database (mySQL) where the table USERS has this structure:

- UserID (varchar)
- Passwd (varchar)
- Name (varchar)
- BancAccount (varchar)

Passwd and BancAccount are plain text on the database. From the PHP code, when login is done, it compares the user input for UserID and Passwd with the results from the database.

I would like to make it more secure, so that if anyone is able to break into the database, he cannot see these two critical fields. Any suggestions?

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the PHP crypt function and use the database to to store the salt as well, to follow up with what Neal says, make sure you try to use some obscurity to hide it as well...but you'll need the salt to compare the user input against later.

[PHP Crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Answer (score 1):

well you can hash with a salt the password. and have a completely seperate table for thebank accounts that is linked somehow to that table but very obscurely.

Comment: Hashing is good. Security by obscurity less so. I'd ignore the second part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not store the password in plain but only a hash of it, at best a [salted hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Which hash function you use and how the salt is chosen is also an important question. [Many people suggest to use *bcrypt* as the hash function for passwords](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) that has a cost parameter to adjust the computational costs of generating the hash value (the more expensive the longer brute-force attacks will last). And the salt should be a random value and unique for each password.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting together a concenated string containing the password; also called to "Salt and Pepper" the password, then encrypt it with SHA1. Then you use the same algorithm when checking the database fields.

```
$salt = "a7s8as98sa9";
$pepper = date("H");

$hash = sha1($salt . $password . $pepper);
```

Using dynamic salts like randomly generated strings, numbers, dates or timestamps are only the tip of the iceberg of creativity.

Comment: Can I ask where this *salt and pepper* concept came from?  I have never heard or seen it before until now (And suffice it to say I have done quite a bit of research on the subject).  Can you point me to any authoritative source on the subject?